# Using selectList in Persistent Haskell MongoDB to return json list

Tags: mongodb, haskell, yesod

I am working on a yesod app. I am trying to write a handler which simply queries a collection and returns all of the results.

In my config/models file the relevant entry is

```
Survey json
    name              String
    questions         [QuestionId]
    deriving (Show)
```

I am working on the following handler:

```
module Handler.ListSurveys where
import Import

getListSurveysR :: Handler Value
getListSurveysR = do
    res :: [Entity Survey]  <-  runDB $ selectList [] [] 
    return   $ object ["surveys" .= res]
```

This is leading to the following error:

```
Handler/ListSurveys.hs:6:41:
    Couldn't match type ‘YesodPersistBackend App’
                   with ‘mongoDB-2.0.7:Database.MongoDB.Query.MongoContext’
    Expected type: YesodDB App [Entity Survey]
      Actual type: ReaderT
                     mongoDB-2.0.7:Database.MongoDB.Query.MongoContext
                     (HandlerT App IO)
                     [Entity Survey]
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘selectList [] []’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      res :: [Entity Survey] <- runDB $ selectList [] []
```

I could really use some help as to understand what is going on with the types here (relatively inexperienced with Haskell) and how to fix this.

Comment: You could also try `res <-  runDB $ selectList ([] :: [Filter Survey]) []`. What does your `instance YesodPersist` look like?